# Can't send request with ksoap2

Tags: android, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"               xmlns:cli="http://www.xxx.com/services/cliente" xmlns:tel="http://www.xxx.com">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
 <cli:ConsultaAbonadoRequest>
<cli:DatosAcceso>
  <tel:nombreAplicacion>AAAA</tel:nombreAplicacion>
</cli:DatosAcceso>
<cli:DatosCelular>
  <tel:numCelular>BBBB</tel:numCelular>
  <tel:numAbonado></tel:numAbonado>
  <tel:codigoCliente></tel:codigoCliente>
</cli:DatosCelular>
</cli:ConsultaAbonadoRequest>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I'm trying to make a SOAP call with ksoap2. I need to send this kind of request. And i spent 3 hours already reading and still can't create sub nodes please help me to make correct envelope

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ksoap2 projects wiki page, [Adding an array of complex objects to the request](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/wiki/CodingTipsAndTricks#Adding_an_array_of_complex_objects_to_the_request) chapter:

To get this xml:

```
<users>
  <user>
     <name>Jonh</name>
     <age>12</age>
  </user>
  <user>
     <name>Marie</name>
     <age>27</age>
  </user>
</users>
```

You would do this:

```
SoapObject users = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "users");
SoapObject john = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "user");
john.addProperty("name", "john");
john.addProperty("age", 12);
SoapObject marie = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "user");
john.addProperty("name", "marie");
john.addProperty("age", 27);
users.addSoapObject(john);
users.addSoapObject(marie);
```

This may help you.

Comment: Thank you you saved a lot of time, now i understand general idea!